# k8s pull image from private registry using service DNS name

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I have a `registry:2` deployed as pod in my kubernetes cluster (running on docker-for-win, WSL2). I have two services for this pod as shown below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: registry-external
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: registry
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5000
      nodePort: 32020
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: registry
spec:
  selector:
    app: registry
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 2100
      targetPort: 5000
```

So the first one for reaching the registry from outside the cluster (on port 32020, so I can `docker login localhost:32020` on the host machine) and one for reaching the registry from the inside (on port 2100).

The login from outside works just fine. I've verified by `nslookup registry` on the cluster, that the registry should be reachable on `registry.default.svc.cluster.local`. So I created my image pull secrets with

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "registry.default.svc.cluster.local:2100": {
            "auth": "......"
        },
    ...
}
```

When I try to deploy a pod with this image pull secret and image `registry.default.svc.cluster.local:2100/animage:latest`
it fails with

```
dial tcp: lookup registry.default.svc.cluster.local on 192.168.65.1:53: no such host
```

I'm puzzled by this: shouldn't the URL be valid at time of image pull?

Comment: The host `registry.default.svc.cluster.local` is a Kubernetes DNS managed hostname. When the worker node pulls an image, it uses the worker node DNS. Have you tried resolving the host `registry.default.svc.cluster.local` on the worker node in terminal (NOT inside a pod). This would be helpful for replicating the issue.

I suspect you will need to give he node port and host.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @JustinTamblyn. That sounds like it could be the issue. Do you know how I can execute the nslookup on the worker node in a k8s cluster on docker-for-win? The entire k8s setup is automatic, so I'm not familiar with how to interact with the worker nodes directly.

Comment: Umm. Thats a tough one. I love the Docker Desktop K8s but I'm afraid I don't know how to run commands on there. I suspect its the same as running commands on the desktop?

Comment: A way to confirm this is to change the image reference to localhost and the nodePort `localhost:3202/...` that should confirm or refute my theory.

Comment: That results in connection refused, but I guess that might be because of missing image pull secrets. I'll try adding that.

Comment: Just to verify: you're suggesting port 3202, because of the `32020` nodePort service. Is the omitted 0 at the end on purpose?

Comment: My mistake, sorry, I did mean the nodePort of 32020

Comment: Right, with `32020` the image pull is successful. So that means the node is effectively in the host network? So no chance of keeping the traffic for the pull internal to k8s?

Comment: That is my understanding as well. Thanks for giving this a try. It was interesting.

Comment: Maybe post this as the answer - someone could benefit from it in the future :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue here is that the pull is executed in an environment where the kubernetes cluster DNS is not available, i.e. a cluster node, but not a cluster pod (in case of kubernetes on docker-for-win, it is executed on the same network as the host).

Since the registry is also exposed with a `NodePort` service, it can be reached on the `nodePort` port 32020 on localhost. Therefore, the image pull secret needs to be adjusted to

```json
{
    "auths": {
        "localhost:32020": {
            "auth": "......"
        },
    ...
}
```

and the image to pull becomes `localhost:32020/animage:latest`.